# Passing variable that changes over time to a Listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, callback, listener

Problem: A listener uses the old value of a variable in a callback.

I'm trying to find a proper way to pass a variable to a callback. The callback should use a relevant value of the variable.

```
const [title, setTitle] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(() => {
      foo(title);
    });

    return () => {/* Removing Listener */};
  }, [])
```

`title` mutates over time, and `foo()` should receive a relevant `title` value.

Solutions that I came up with so far:

1. Keep value in useRef() instead of useState()
2. Destroy and re-create listener on change `title`

But non of them looks like optimal approach. Please help.

Comment: Found something similar in react docs:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-read-an-often-changing-value-from-usecallback

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating anonymous function, you can create a function for listener and wrap it in useCallback

```
const callbackFunc = useCallback(()=>{
    foo(title)
},[title])
```

now your useEffect will be

```
useEffect(() => {
    notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(callbackFunc);

    return () => {/* Removing Listener */};
}, [])
```

Comment: It doesn't work, unless add "callbackFunc" to the useEffect dependency list. But this would be the same as keeping "title" in the useEffect dependency list.